# Define/set PHP variable

Tags: php, session-variables

I often get PHP errors about a variable not defined. I'm also wondering what is best practice for setting session variables. Currently I'm doing this:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["myVar"]))
  $_SESSION["myVar"] = "";
```

But this seems untidy to me. I know there is a PHP `unset` function, but what is the equivalent to simply set/define a variable into existence, without setting an initial value?

Comment: Just a normal var or session var?

Comment: For now, a session var, but I also wonder the best way to be defining variables in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Php has dynamic variable allocation and typing. When a variable is first referenced within a program, memory is allocated for its use.

Meaning that unless you don't assign a value, a variable can't be declared, like say, in java.

Best way how to make sure you "declare" all your variables?

- Assign them to null or empty string **at the beginning** of each function / method.

About session variables, I'd apply the same logic.

Comment: So in this case `$_SESSION["myVar"] = "";` would be correct?

Comment: Yes. If you think your variable type might change in runtime, then maybe assign as `null` in the beginning.